# Installing a specific device from Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

As part of a troubleshooting script, I want to install a problematic device from powershell, but can't find any way to do that

Our environment blocks TB3 devices (PCI-PCI bridge in DM), and every time an OS build upgrade is happening, the devices needs to be installed again.
The restriction comes from hklm:SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions
I created some script that removes the restriction, and another that re-enables it afterwards, but the actual part that installs the missing driver from MS, that I can't do.

Comment: What have you tried so far. Update you anwer with some code ...

Comment: Can't really find any way to access the device manager. Only thing I have is the code to remove the restrictions

Comment: Have a look at the _PNPUtil.exe_ and _DevCon.exe_: [How to Manage Device Drivers with Command Line](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/181.how-to-manage-device-drivers-with-command-line.aspx)